# How to use html() of jquery over specific child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `html()` function of jquery over the specific child like:

```
<div id="main">
  <p>I am p tag</p>
  <span> i am span tag</span>
</div>
```

Now if we use `$("#main").html()` it gives both `p` and `span` but if i want only `p`, what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$("#main p").html()
```

> This will give me I am p tag but i want `<p> I am p tag</p>`

Try below for outerHTML,

```
$('#main p')[0].outerHTML
```

Or you can make it as jQuery function so you can chain.

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    var _this = this[0];
    return _this.outerHTML?_this.outerHTML:(s ? this.before(s).remove() : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html());
};

$('#main p').outerHTML()
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/PMjKR/1/

**Ref:** [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Comment: This will give me `I am p tag` but i want `<p> I am p tag</p>`

Comment: he needs to get the html including the p tag.. by doing your method it would return the html contents **within** the `<p></p>` in which case there is not html, just text. You need to use outerHTML

Answer (score 2):

Many ways depending on your exact requirements.

Standard css selector:

```
$('#main p').html();
```

filtering on children.

```
$('#main').children('p').html();
```

by getting the first child of main

```
$('#main:first-child').html();
```

**EDIT**
after seeing comment on another answer by OP i will simply add where html() is replace with [0].outerHTML

see [selectors here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)